# Selenium: How to find the element from the HTML provided through CssSelector or XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is a button on the page:

```
<button data-purpose="add-section-btn" type="button" 
        class="ellipsis btn btn-default btn-block">
   <span class="a3 udi udi-plus-square"></span>
   <!-- react-text: 255 --> <!-- /react-text -->
   <!-- react-text: 256 -->Add Section<!-- /react-text -->
</button>
```

When I try to find it using the following code:

```
var btns = _driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button"));
var sectionTitle = btns.Where(x => x.GetAttribute("data-purpose") == "add-section-btn");
```

It returns null.

If I try the following XPath:

```
var btn = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[data-purpose=\"add-section-btn\"]"));
```

then I get an exception.

How to find such a button?

Comment: Have you tried LinkText ?

Comment: can you paste which exception are you getting? detailed stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
var btn = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@data-purpose='add-section-btn']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to find the element with text as **Add Section** as the element is a [**React Element**](https://reactjs.org/) you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  var btn = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("button.ellipsis.btn.btn-default.btn-block[data-purpose='add-section-btn']")));
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  var btn = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//button[@class='ellipsis btn btn-default btn-block' and @data-purpose='add-section-btn'][normalize-space()='Add Section']")));
  ```